# Visual Artifacts in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS 2010 on Windows Server 2003, running on a Dell Inspiron 9400 laptop. VS 2010 runs fine, except for persistent and random screen re-drawing issues. [Samples of these are here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMwWp.jpg)

These artifacts occur as the mouse moves over items that highlight on a mouse-over event, while scrolling, and when switching tabs. VS 2008 has non of these issues, so I assume that it is related to VS 2010's use of WPF. Could it be that my video card or driver is not up to the task of rendering WPF? Some other WPF applications (not Silverlight) also have some of these screen repainting problems.

I have tried a variety of settings in System Properties-->Advanced-->Performance Options-->Visual Effects, and in the related "Advanced" tab, Processor Scheduling is adjusted for best performance of programs.

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I didn't note that problem on my installation, but I saw a blurred effect on fonts used in the text editor. I solved using another type of font (Courier New instead of Consolas).

Comment: Might be a problem similar to http://superuser.com/questions/45296/display-glitches-in-windows-7-on-dell-latitude-xt2 – Especially if you didn't enable Aero it would only be visible where hardware-accelerated drawing is used, for example in WPF.

Comment: @Johannes: Many thanks for the link! I hope Intel has been able to help you.

Comment: Read the comments to the answer to that question. Disabling VT-d fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio uses WPF which used the video card alot more than traditional GDI applications, I'd check your card drivers and make sure they're up to date.

Comment: Thanks Lavinski. You are correct. Let that be a lesson to us all ;-) WPF takes its toll on older video cards and their original drivers. VS 2010 has hundreds, maybe thousands, of WPF objects making DirectX calls to keep the UI rendered.

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered for a while but I just fixed a similar issue with screen artifacting I was receiving in editor views of a MVC3 application.  I'm running on a Core i7 3960X 6 core processor, the graphics card is a Radeon HD 6950 2GB.  Needless to say, I shouldn't be getting these issues.  It looked to be something related to my graphics card because going to Tools > Options and then unselecting "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available" caused the issue to stop occurring -

[image: VS Options]